# Uncaught TypeError in Chrome and Not a Function in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-events

I want to set the variable zoom as the `map.GetZoom()` but I have been getting the following error in both Chrome and Firefox:

*Chrome*

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getZoom'

*Firefox*

> gmap.getZoom is not a function
> zoom = gmap.getZoom();

**First question** What error did I make in my codes?

*default.js*

```
window.gmap = {
 zoom_Changed: function() {

 zoom = gmap.getZoom();

 if(zoom > 15) {
  document.write("hello");
 } else {
 } 
 }
};
```

**Edit:** `Gmap` is defined in my views.py and the zoom_Changed function is for the event listener in my views.py.

**views.py**

```
maps.event.addListener(gmap, 'zoom_changed', 'gmap.zoom_Changed');
```

Comment: Are you using Google Maps? Because, otherwise, you're just creating some object `gmap`. You call `gmap.getZoom`, but you never define what that is.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Google Maps. Gmap is defined in my Django views.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `zoom = gmap.getZoom();`, it should be `zoom = this.getZoom();`.

Answer (score 0):

is it `getZoom()` or `GetZoom()`?  Casing is different in the question and the code example.

what @silverbtf is saying is partially right, i believe, (hard for me to test on the netbook i'm on). however by setting `gmap` again to an object literal (`window.gmap = {...}`), you're wiping out any existing `gmap` variable attached to the `window` object.

you could possibly rewrite your code like this:

```
gmap.zoom_Changed = function () {
    var zoom = this.getZoom(); // or .GetZoom()
    if (zoom > 15) {
        console.log('over 15');
    } else {
        console.log('under 15');
    }
}
```

this way, you're attaching a new method to the already existing `gmap` instead of blowing it away.